# Use of PHP cloud apps in .Net web framework

Tags: c#, php, .net, cloud

My question in it's most basic terms is this: Could I develop an app in PHP to live in the cloud which I could use on websites that are built in the .NET framework?

I am asking this because an app (C# developed) which has been developed for use on my website (.NET) is now static and has to be added to pages in an iframe which causes a whole host of issues in terms of resizing, communicating with internal data, etc. Also, to change this app would mean going through the long-winded process of changing all my source files and recompiling the application.

The application in the future will have to be scalable in that it will be used on 26 international websites who use different languages. I know that using a cloud based app would be better for me in that it would essentially be table driven (pull the software file from this location and the language (XML) from another location and store to this remote database).

My choice of PHP comes from the fact that this is my language of choice and am already comfortable using it. It also offers all the functionality that I need within the app.

So overall,

1. Would it be better to use the cloud for this application?
2. Would I be able to use any language to develop the app and include it in the .NET framework?
3. Should I just leave this method and develop it as an application that I can just embed on a webpage?

Thanks for all your suggestions if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little hard if your using a php SAAS (Software as a Service) AKA a php application.

It is fine to be stored and loaded from the cloud AKA Amazon Cloud Servers how every if your wanting this in the .net application your best way would be to just use the WebBrowser control if your happy using IE7 if your wanting a more up-to-date browser i would say use http://awesomium.com as it provides a very easy to understand and use API for you to change things like dynamically linking to different addresses passing C# application code into your browser's JavaScript so a web site can call system properties.
Then you would be able to detect the client (the .net application computer) and send though the localization as a GET on the string that can then set a SESSION for your application to show the correct lang

i have lot's of experience in setting up applications like so if you need any help please don't hesitate to send me a private message

If i have misunderstood what your wanting please tell me and i will remove answer

Comment: no you have not misunderstood. I am thinking to get rid of the current application in C# and write it purely in PHP. How to access and communicate with the PHP app is the hardest thing for me. How do I send private messages?

Comment: Can't find the discussion thing now put pop into this room and i help http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8627/asp-net-c